# How can I test Omniauth with postman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, mobile, devise

I'm creating an API with Rails and Omniauth Facebook for a native app, but I don't know how to test the Log-In with postman. I'm passing a token example created with Graph API Explorer (Tools & Support)

request postman:

```
localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/facebook/callback?access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAORMwRgkhEEuceAh1TJCrgLCcRQuWOb6nJ7RRZBKCYHQFsZAtjco93iA29G4jZAFhHK5XMWr1TEZAXgxEBUzVVZBIwIxqLmQwAPg0YQyum9UIVd7pDSn51l34ZAtzvpIdJ8c7vR0L2eWZBZBgR3LOjxnRH3vTjZA2brvnhnZAh05JnNx4BjDZCEBgAZD&resource_class=User
```

I got always this error:

> app/controllers/devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:150:in
>   `devise_mapping'

I realized that request.env are empty

> controllers/devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
def omniauth_params
  if !defined?(@_omniauth_params)
    if request.env['omniauth.params'] && request.env['omniauth.params'].any?
      @_omniauth_params = request.env['omniauth.params']
    elsif session['dta.omniauth.params'] && session['dta.omniauth.params'].any?
      @_omniauth_params ||= session.delete('dta.omniauth.params')
      @_omniauth_params
    elsif params['omniauth_window_type']
      @_omniauth_params = params.slice('omniauth_window_type', 'auth_origin_url', 'resource_class', 'origin')
    else
      @_omniauth_params = {}
    end
  end
  @_omniauth_params

end
```

This is my app configuration:

[image]

This is my ominauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx',
    callback_path: 'api/v1/auth/facebook/callback'
end
```